# Residual current relay continuity

Tags: ac, relay, protection, leakage-current

Even if the leakage current relay is 300 mA, it cannot provide human protection in such a case. Then, if I make a circuit like this, if there is already 270 mA leakage, then if there is an extra 30 mA leakage, it will switch to the relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhXLQK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even if this circuit works, will it cause any damage to the leakage current relay?

**NOT:** *The rest of the electrical installation is ignored. ALSO, it is assumed that the device operates with 270 mA current.*

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about the precise question you are asking?  Is it whether you can assume 30mA protection using a 300mA RCD and 270mA of "base" leakage?  If so, the answer is a definite NO, both because of the variation in operating point of the 300mA RCD, and because the 270mA leakage can't be assumed to be stable.

Comment: @colintd Assuming 270ma leakage is constant, will 30ma provide protection? and will the relay be damaged?

Comment: @colintd For me, what is important here is not the protection feature of the relay, but whether the relay will be damaged or not.

Comment: The RCD should not be damaged by triggering at its design leakage trip point, as long as the interrupted current is within the design range.  Most devices will have durability limits of 1000s of trips.

Comment: As to "protection", you absolutely can't assume that a 300mA RCD will provide "protection" at the 30mA level by ensuring there is 270mA of background leakage, partly because of variability in the background leakage, and partly because the % error in the trip point will mean you can't be sure of 30mA "remaining" sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RCD should not be damaged by triggering at its design leakage trip point, as long as the interrupted current is within the design range. Most devices will have durability limits of 1000s of trips.

As to "protection", you absolutely **can't** assume that a 300mA RCD will provide "protection" at the 30mA level by ensuring there is 270mA of background leakage.  This partly because of variability in the background leakage, and partly because the % error in the trip point will mean you can't be sure of 30mA "remaining" sensitivity.

Comment: I want to understand this for sure. If we pass less than 300ma (protection) current through the RCD continuously throughout the day, it will not shorten the life of the RCD.

Comment: No issue at all.  The currents going through the transformer core of the RCD will be the L & N currents, with the difference leading to a voltage in the RCD secondary proportional to the leakage current in the primary circuit.  If this exceeds the threshold then the unit will trip, but it is explicitly designed to withstand all sub-trip levels indefinitely.  In fact high background leakage levels in large industrial setups is one of the key reason for 300mA RCD, which are essentially there to provide fire protection.